# Trying to get property of non-object when trying to access array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to access a array via its index, but I need to get this from the query string.

I've tried:

```
 $var = $_GET['id'];
 echo $xml->subway->line[$var]->name;
```

That doesn't work. But this does:

```
 echo $xml->subway->line[0]->name;
```

Comment: What is `echo $_GET['id'];`?

Comment: can you post your form?

Comment: Try to use `intval($_GET['id'])`. Its interpreting the `$var` as string `'0'` perhaps.

Comment: @RahilWazir Does not matter whether its a string or an integer, if its set in array PHP will find it.

Comment: @GGio Yup it doesn't matter. But if `$_GET['id']` is not set it will still return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$var = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : false;

if ($var !== false && isset($xml->subway->line[$var]) {
   echo $xml->subway->line[$var]->name;
} else {
   echo 'Your problem is either "id" not being in $_GET or $xml object does not have line with that index';

   var_dump($_GET); //see what is 'id'
}
```

Everytime you are getting item from an array by index you should check if it is **set** first to avoid errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your `$_GET` variable is coming back as a `string` instead of an `integer` so PHP will be assuming the index doesn't exist. Try type casting it as

```
$var = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Which forces PHP to treat the `$_GET` as an `integer`

Comment: you could check it yourself that whether $var is a string or integer $array index will still be set. so if `$id = '0'; $arr[0] = 'Hello';` by doing `echo $arr[$id];` will return `Hello`

Comment: @GGio It definitely should do that but I've had some problems with $_GET values not working as indexes before, type casting seemed the only (albeit forceful) solution

Comment: @user3528831 I've just set up my own test and doing either `intval($_GET['id'])` or `(int) $_GET['id']` is working ok, would you be able to update the answer with your xml structure?